# Setting Up NetTcpBinding

Tags: c#, wcf-binding

Setting Up NetTcpBinding. I get an error when trying to get data from the server.
Were tested using WCFTestClient.

I'm new to WCF. I may have missed the IIS setting or made a mistake in the binding. Please help us understand the problem.

```
The message with To
'net.tcp://wssekbdev-5-loc.wss.loc/_layouts/WSS/WSSC.V4.DMS.TestWCF.WcfService1/Service3.svc' cannot be processed at the receiver, due to an AddressFilter mismatch at the EndpointDispatcher.  Check that the sender and receiver's EndpointAddresses agree.
      Server stack trace:     at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.ThrowIfFaultUnderstood(Message reply, MessageFault fault, String action, MessageVersion version, FaultConverter faultConverter)    at
      System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.HandleReply(ProxyOperationRuntime operation, ProxyRpc& rpc)    at
 System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)    at
 System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)    at
 System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)
 
 Exception rethrown at [0]:     at
 System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessagereqMsg, IMessage retMsg)    at
 System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)    at
 IServiceContract.Login(String username)    at
 ServiceContractClient.Login(String username)
```

[image]

Code Server

```
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
[ServiceBehavior(AddressFilterMode = AddressFilterMode.Any)]
public class ServiceTest : IServiceContract
{
    public string Login(string username)
    {
        return $"ok:{username}";
    }

    public void Message(string message, string userFrom)
    {
         
    }
}

[ServiceContract()]
public interface IServiceContract
{
    [OperationContract]
    string Login(string username);

    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
    void Message(string message, string userFrom);
}
```

Configuration

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true" />
  </system.webServer> 
  <system.web> 
    <httpRuntime />
    <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" />
    <compilation targetFramework="4.5" />
        <identity impersonate="false" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    
    <bindings> 
      <netTcpBinding>
        <binding name="TestBinding" sendTimeout="00:01:00">
          <reliableSession ordered="true" enabled="false" />
          <security mode="None" /> 
        </binding>
      </netTcpBinding>  
    </bindings>
    <services>
 
      <service name="WSSC.V4.DMS.TestWCF.WcfService1.ServiceTest">
        <endpoint binding="netTcpBinding" contract="WSSC.V4.DMS.TestWCF.WcfService1.IServiceContract"
                  bindingConfiguration="TestBinding"
                  />
 
        <endpoint binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="WSSC.V4.DMS.TestWCF.WcfService1.IServiceContract"/>
        
        <endpoint address = "mex" binding = "mexTcpBinding" contract = "IMetadataExchange" /> 
      </service>


    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior > 
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors> 
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: There is no problem with your service, because I successfully run it.

Comment: Can you tell me what went wrong when calling the service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your service is running in Visual Studio Development Server, you cannot configure netTcpBinding. The reason is that Visual Studio Development Server only supports HTTP.

You need to change the project properties like below:

[image]

**You can also tell me what error occurred when you call the service, I can help you solve it.**

I created a WCF project deployed in IIS based on the information you provided, but did not find any errors.

Make sure the following service is running:

[image]

Feel free to let me know if the problem persists.

Answer (score 0):

The project settings were specified correctly.
I restarted IIS, restarted services, and it worked.
Thank you so much for your help.